# warning: cast increases required alignment of target type on hardware

Tags: c

I am trying to run a my project on ARM like processor (Client provided IP)  which has this warning like :

```
warning: cast increases required alignment of target type
```

My sample c code is :

```
short mvglobal[2] = {10, 20};

void calculate_mv(short mv[], int check) {

    if(check == 0) {
        *((int *)&(mv[0])) = 0;
        *((int *)&(mv[1])) = 0;
    } else {
  
        *((int *)&(mv[0])) = *((int *)&(mvglobal[0]));
        *((int *)&(mv[1])) = *((int *)&(mvglobal[1]));
    }
}

int main() {

  int check = 0 ; // can be 1 also..Coming from other part of code.
  short mv[2]  __attribute__((aligned(32)));
  mv[0] = 125;
  mv[1] = 100;
     
  calculate_mv(mv, check);
  
  return 0;
}
```

I am getting same warning at

```
*((int *)&(mv[0])) = 0;
*((int *)&(mv[0])) = *((int *)&(mvglobal[0]));
```

I tried to use memcpy which doesnot work and getting wrong result

```
memcpy(&mv[0], &mvglobal[0], sizeof(int));
```

Is there any way to fix this warning.

Comment: Why are you casting to `int*`? `short*` probably has different alignment requirements on your "ARM-like processor" (say, 2-byte alignment vs 4-byte alignment of `int*`). The `aligned` attribute of your `short`-array in `main` doesn't "propagate" to `calculate_mv`; `calculate_mv` must work with any `short`-array, including those that aren't `int`-aligned.

Comment: In addition to invoking undefined behavior should the cast to `int *` violate any alignment restrictions, the code always invokes undefined behavior by violating [strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).

Comment: my processor has 4 byte alignments.

Comment: @mahesh narlekar The presented code does not make sense.

Comment: What is the reason you are using short in the first place? Saving RAM?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, I made it simple to put this code here. I need to copy that mv to the short mv array.But that array is 4 byte aligned. I want to make sure that copying doesn't break the alignment.

Comment: @maheshnarlekar And why memcpy and memset do not work?

Comment: @maheshnarlekar Is it alignment of the whole array or of each its element short mv[2]  __attribute__((aligned(32)));?

Comment: @maheshnarlekar What does prevent you to write  mv[0] = mvglobal[0];
        mv[1] = mvglobal[1];?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, on simulator that works. But on hardware I need to aligned the motion vectors with 4 byte.

Comment: So you aren't using a 4 byte type simply because that would have been to easy? Instead you pick a 2 byte type and tell the compiler to discard 2 bytes between them... (or actually 30 bytes)

Comment: Do you have an array of two-byte integers and need the values in an array of four-byte integers?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fundamentally broken, and you do not explain what its purpose is, so no fix can be given without further information.

As for the problem you ask about, the `mv` parameter to `calculate_mv` does not have the `aligned` attribute, so the compiler cannot presume it has any more alignment than is required for `short`. The fact that `main` calls it with a pointer to an aligned array is irrelevant because `calculate_mv` is a separate routine that must serve any caller, and its parameter does not have an `aligned` attribute. (Even though there is no caller in the source file you show, this source file could be linked with others that do call `calculate_mv`.)

Second, if you do declare the parameter to be aligned, say with four-byte alignment, that only makes the start of the array aligned. So `mv[0]` would be aligned to a multiple of four bytes, but `mv[1]` would not, because it immediately follows `mv[0]`, which is two bytes in your C implementation.

So that is one way your program is fundamentally broken: It is not possible for `mv[0]` and `mv[1]`, which are two bytes apart, to both be aligned to multiples of four bytes.

(Also note the `aligned` attribute uses a number of bytes, not bits. You probably want `aligned(4)`, not `aligned(32)`.)

Another way your program is broken is that if violates the strict aliasing rules. When elements of an array defined as using `short` are accessed with a type `int`, the C standard does not define the behavior. This problem does not mean your program is fundamentally broken because some C implementation support this sort of aliasing, with a command-line switch. However, this will not solve your problems because of the other errors.

Another way in which your program is fundamentally broken is that `mv` is declared to be an array of two two-byte `short` elements, making it four bytes in total, and so is `myglobal`. When you access them with `*((int *)&(mv[1]))` and `*((int *)&(mvglobal[1]))`, you attempt to access four bytes starting two bytes into the array. And thus you access beyond the array bounds. Again, the behavior for that is not defined by the C standard, and this is not something compilers will normally support.

There is no apparent reason to access either array beyond bounds. It is not apparent why you are trying to do this or what goal you are trying to achieve. There is no fix for the code as it stands.

> I tried to use memcpy which doesnot work and getting wrong result

That is not an adequate problem description. **Never** describe code just as “does not work.” Always state what behavior was observed and what behavior was desired instead and what evidence led you to conclude the code did not work. And show the non-working code so that other people can analyze it.

Comment: Why there is no solution with union use for mv ??  Its my thinking after this reply read.

Comment: union {
    short mv_short[2];
    int mv_int[2];
} mv_union;

Comment: @maheshnarlekar Again, what is the actual problem you are trying to solve? It is still perfectly unlear why you can't simply use an array of `uint32_t`/`int32_t`.

Comment: @Lundin  mv are the motion vectors in x and y direction and positive and negative also..mv[0] is x and mv[1] is y direction motion vector. can also make it int like int mv[0] but I have limited data memory.

Comment: @maheshnarlekar So the best solution would be to just declare them as an array of `int16_t` and let the compiler worry about alignment. C compilers do not misalign variables as some sort of confused default setting - rather they go at lengths to ensure aligned access when the data types are known. And besides, your ISA likely supports 16 bit words too.

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to say what your code is intended to do as probably it comes from a lack of experience. It is broken and @EricPostpischil has explained it very well.

Your code can be reduced to:

````
void calculate_mv1(short mv[], int check) {

    if(check == 0) {
        mv[0] = 0;
        mv[1] = 0;
    } else {
        mv[0] = mvglobal[0];
        mv[1] = mvglobal[1];
    }
}
```
or
```
void calculate_mv(short mv[], int check) {

    if(check == 0) {
        memset(mv, 0, sizeof(*mv) * 2);
    } else {
        memcpy(mv, mvglobal, sizeof(mvglobal));
    }
}
```
````